# HOW TO INSERT JSON (PostgreSQL )

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I want to insert JSON with the value of the array from postgrsql to value into JSON-type columns. What should I do?

```
CREATE TABLE jsonlist (col JSON);

INSERT INTO jsonlist(col)
VALUES ('{"usrGrp":"{1,2,3}"}');
```

Comment: In JSON arrays are surrounded by square brackets `[1,2,3]`

Answer (score 1):

I got it:

```
'{"action":"del","usrId": ["yjshin","test111"],"usrGrpId": [1,2]}'
```

You can use brackets to tie up what you want to make a list. Note that in the array, the string had to enclose each element in double quotes, and the entire JSON had to be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the question. To insert JSON you just need to pack it into a string literal (or pass it as parameter in a prepared statement). It behaves like regular strings, JSON doesn't need any special treatment. You're seemingly asking how to encode arrays in JSON, which is a different thing.